Derivative of the tetration function
I realize this question has been asked before and a solution has been found. I wanted to tackle this problem myself and stumbled into a diffrent area of mathematics and I wanted maybe some help with looking for a solution goint about it a diffrent way.
By looking for a solution I found the recursive formula
$$ \frac{d}{dx}[{^{n}{x}}]=([{^{n-1}{x}}]^{\prime}\ln{x}+\frac{{^{n-1}{x}}}{x}){^{n}{x}}$$
Which can be written in more recurrence relation form as
$$ a_{n}=(a_{n-1}\ln{x}+\frac{{^{n-1}{x}}}{x}){^{n}{x}}$$
Now as for my background I am in calculus 1 but I've had some time to look around the block of Wikipedia articles and play around with summation and products and the like. I learnt about recurrence relations in my discrete class recently and managed to find through a friend of mine that this can be expressed as a first order general non-homogeneous recurrence relation.  I was wondering if someone could give me tip on how I could go about solving it. Anything to push me in the right direction. I tried to express, after multiplying in the ${^{n}{x}}$ term, the tetrarion as multiples of some function of x that way I can manipulate it and solve for a pattern but that got me stuck inside a super logarithm and I'm a little stumped. I have a vague idea of what to do but that's about it.
